# is there a nodejs equivalent of php get_class function to detect exact type of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a class like

```
function FooClass() {
    this.data = {
        foo: null,
        bar: null,
    }
}
```

and its instance

```
let instance = new FooClass()
```

is there a nodejs equivalent of php get_class function to detect exact type of a javascript object? Actually I know just `typeof` function but I only detect that an instance is 'object'.

```
'object' === typeof instance
```

What I need is a sort of

```
('FooClass' === getClass(instance)) // `true`
```

is there?

Comment: `instance instanceof FooClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Object.getPrototypeOf(instance)**
Or
**if(instance.constructor === FooClass) // true**

Comment: `instance.prototype.constructor` seems very wrong. That means `instance` a function. Can you explain what each of those is supposed to return?

Comment: if(instance.constructor === FooClass) // true

Comment: That is true, but what does this have to do with your answer?

Comment: that is what I mean it in my short answer answer

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` is most likely what your looking for..

```js
function FooClass() {
    this.data = {
        foo: null,
        bar: null,
    }
}

let instance = new FooClass();

if (instance instanceof FooClass) {
  console.log("I am FooClass");
}
```